# Mockito: how to mock the behaviour of function of another class inside functionToBeTested?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have function that I want to test (**confirmOrder**), that needs an object **"Customer customer"** that is defined by calling the method from another class **"CustomerManagement"** with a function call **customerManagement.getVerifiedCustomer()**

I want to mock the customerManagement class so that when the function is called in my ClassBeingTested (CartController), it uses the obeject "Customer" that I want.

So I tried the usual methods of mocking the class CustomerManagement and a **when().thenReturn()** function from Mockito to no avail. Creating a spy of the CustomerManagementClass worked even worse, since Mockito threw out an error affirming that the class cannot be mocked. (note that mocking throws now errors).

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("cart")
@GetMapping("/orderScreen/orderConfirm")
CustomerOrder order;

public String confirmOrder(@RequestParam("decide")  String decider, @ModelAttribute Cart cart) {

    Customer customer = customerManagement.getVerifiedCustomer();
    order = new CustomerOrder(customer);

    if(decider.equals("takeItYourself")){
        order.setDeliverableState(false);
    } else {
        order.setDeliverableState(true);
    }

    if (cart.getPrice().isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(Money.of(30, EURO))){
        return "redirect:freeBeverage";
    }
    createOrder(cart);
    return "redirect:complete";

}


@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CartControllerTest{

    @Autowired
    CartController cartController;

    Customer customer;
    CustomerManagement customerManagement;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        initMocks(this);
        customer = new Customer("Jane", "Doe", "123");

        customerManagement = mock(CustomerManagement.class)
        when(customerManagement.getVerifiedCustomer()).thenReturn(customer);

        cartToEmpy = new Cart();
        cartToEmpy.addOrUpdateItem(beverage, 3);
    }

    @Test
    public void confirmOrderPickUp(){
        String decider = "takeItYourself";

        String returnedView = cartController.confirmOrder(decider, cartToEmpy);

        assertThat(returnedView).isEqualTo("redirect:complete");
    }
}
```

So when I run this test class, it completely ignores the **when().thenReturn()** and runs the function with the **Customer customer** object from my class being tested which of course throws an **IllegalArgumentException** since this Customer is set on null and the Constructor CustomerOrder does not take null Customer objects.

Note that I cannot change the code of the classes and must therefore find a way to test this.

PowerMock is also sadly not option since it seems to not like jdk 9 and running in conjunction with Mockito. I have tried and wasted hours on this.

I am really starting to get desperate since I have other similar functions I have to test where I have to mock other returns from functions called withon the function I want to test. Thank you in advance for any help available.

Comment: How are you injecting `mock customerManagement` into `cartController`?

Comment: Is the method `getVerifiedCustomer()` static or final by any chance?

Comment: I solved it, thank you sagarr. I had not injected my mock in my cartController() constructor. Your question lead me to check and I cannot believe I've lost so much time on this but thank you so much for your help.